Does symmetricy of relation implies that it consists only of same elements in ordered pair
I am reading Dudley's "Real analysis and probability" paragraph 1.2.
There are concept of relation $E$ which is set of partial orderings ($<x,y>=\{\{x,y\},x\}$).
Inverse relation is $E^{-1}=\{<y,x>:<x,y> \in E\}$.
Relation $E$ is called symmetric iff $E = E^{-1}$.
Now imagine that we have $E=\{<a_1,b_1>;...;<a_n,b_n>\}$. If E is symmetric, then $E^{-1}=\{<a_1,b_1>;...;<a_n,b_n>\}$. $E^{-1}=\{<y,x>:<x,y> \in E\}$ also implies that $a_i = b_i$ for each i in between 1 and $n$ if $E$ is symmetric.
So does it means that if $E$ is symmetric, then it contains only partial orderings that looks like $<x_i,x_i>$?
For example:

$E = \{<1,2>;<2,3>\}$, then $E^{-1} = {<2,1>;<3,2>}$. This is not symmetric, because $E=E^{-1}$ does not holds.
$E = \{<1,1>;<2,2>\}$, $E^{-1} = \{<1,1>;<2,2>\}$. This is symmetric and $E^{-1}$ contains only $<y,x>$ while $E$ contains $<x,y>$.

